# Azure B2C Custom Policies local account KMSI doesn't keep me signed in

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I implemented the steps in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started?tabs=app-reg-preview#create-the-signing-key) - all worked as expect to this point - and then I followed the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in) to enable KMSI.

When testing Identity Experience Framework->Custom Policies->B2C_1A_signup_signin ->Run , I can switch on the tickbox "Keep me signed in" when signing in. However, I close this window (or keep it open for that matter), Run the custom policy again and asks me to sign in again ("Keep me signed in" shows unticked).

I have triple checked the changes in the tutorial and example and can't see any difference (other than in the [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/scenarios/keep%20me%20signed%20in/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml) I don't have LoadURI and RecoveryURI.

I note I have not made changes as per [ContentDefinitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#datauri) and only followed the instructions in enable [KMSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in) because I didn't think that was a requirement in the tutorial.

Please give me some guidance what may be wrong. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong method to test the KMSI feature.

If you "Run the custom policy again", it will always ask you to reenter your credential, which is by-design.

You should follow the steps of [Test your policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in#test-your-policy).

You can close the window after you sign in for the first time.
And then follow the step 4, 5 and 6:

> 4. Go back to the Azure portal. Go to the policy page, and then select **Copy** to copy the sign-in URL.
> 5. In the browser address bar, remove the `&prompt=login` query string parameter, which forces the user to enter their credentials on that
>      request.
> 6. In the browser, click **Go**. Now Azure AD B2C will issue an access token without prompting you to sign-in again.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

You don't need to replace the `SignUpOrSignin.xml` and `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`. Just refer to my changes:

Add the following code snippet into the **BuildingBlocks** element in `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`.

```
<ContentDefinitions>
    <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/unified.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
  </ContentDefinitions>
```

And then add the following node as a child of the  element. It must be located immediately after `<DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="User journey Id" />`.

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" KeepAliveInDays="30" />
  <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
  <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1200</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

These are all the changes need to be made.

You don't need to remove `&prompt=login` in the files. Please see my screenshot above. After you copy the sign-in URL, it will be like this:

```
https://**.b2clogin.com/**.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SignUpOrSignIn&client_id=**&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login
```

Just remove the `&prompt=login` at the end of the URL and access it in a new window.

Comment: Thank you @Allen Wu , yes I missed that step and works to test, but the concern is that in real life, calling the web app linked to these custom flows doesn't keep me signed in once I close the browser. Do I need to make any further changes to what's on the tutorial that I implemented? I don't see somewhere to remove &prompt=login in the files uploaded for the tutorial and KMSI additions. Thank you

Comment: I followed the steps in the tutorial links I show in the post and also replaced SignUpOrSignin.xml and TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml found at the git repo active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/scenarios/keep me signed in/ , can't find what I'm missing

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Allen Wu , it was driving me mad hahaha, it was firefox setup to delete cookies when browser closes! dohhhh... thanks again for your invaluable help!